# How to get sorted values in below structure

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database structure]

I want to get sorted data as.... **value1--value2--value3....value10--value11**

Comment: Do Arraylist sort .

Comment: You'll have to sort an arrayList by overridding the comparator to match your requirements.

Comment: is there any way to get data from firebase as value1--value2--value3....value10--value11... I dont want to sort arraylist

Answer (score 1):

String values are sorted lexicographically. If you want them to be sorted in the order you want, you'll need to ensure that the lexicographical order matches your needs, e.g. pad the numbers in your keys to all be the same length:

```
"value01": ...
..
"value09": ...
"value10": ...
```

I wrote a longer answer on this a while ago, see: [Firebase query ordering not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174300/firebase-query-ordering-not-working-properly/37192471#37192471)